# Location app high battery usage - NlpWakeLock high time and app stops working after some time

Tags: android

I have app which should periodially send device location to the server, even when phone is not used.

There are **AlarmManager** ticks which starts IntentService that binds to the **Location Service** for a while (20s) and then sends location gathered by that service.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver_.class);
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 2, intent, 0);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+ALARM_TIME, ALARM_TIME, sender);
```

**Location Service** is Service (type: START_STICKY), which should be running constantly. Its currently using multiple providers

```
mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
mLocationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

It starts the providers when its bound by some component (Activity, or IntentService - so app is or foreground or on background while IntentService started by alarm is making periodicall location check)

```
if (mIsBound) {
  if (mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
   provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
   mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 0, LocationService.this);
 }
 if (mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
  provider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
  mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 0, LocationService.this);
 }

 LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
 mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000);
 mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(2500);             
 mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY); mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest,mLocationCallback,null);
}
```

And shuts down the providers when its not bound by any component (app is on background and alarm tick is not occuring now)

```
mLocationManager.removeUpdates(LocationService.this);
mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);
```

So when app is on background and alarm ticks interval is set to like 60mins, it most of the time shouldn't be gathering location at all.

But still the app has **very big battery usage** on background and after some hours the whole app probably gets killed by the system - **alarm ticks stops occuring** and I dont see app or the Location Service in the running apps on my phone. Is system killing it because high battery usage?

Here are some interesting battery stats I gathered about the app while it was running for +-2 hours. It has high NlpWakeLock time. Other apps performing same task has this wakelock on like 14min

```
Wifi Running: 39m 6s 460ms (29,7%)
Full Wifi Lock: 1h 22m 59s 653ms (63,1%)
Wifi Scan: 3s 663ms (0,0%)

Wake lock NlpCollectorWakeLock realtime
Wake lock *alarm*: 346ms partial (33 times) realtime
Wake lock NlpWakeLock: 1h 22m 1s 153ms partial (25 times) realtime
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/power/index.html

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling.html

Comment: Try the above implementations on your project.